# Find all elements on a webpage with fixed widths

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like to find all elements on a webpage with fixed widths rather than % widths. Can javascript do this? I actually doubt it. It seems that you'd need dev tools so you can preprocess the CSS, or rather analyze it before it is used by the browser, i.e., the JS. Thoughts?

The use cases are 3rd-party iframes. Below I show a chat widget from [Tawk.to](http://tawk.to/%22Tawk.to%22), which as you can see offsets the page because some element on the page has a pixel, i.e., fixed width. [image]

Comment: Short answer: yes. Long answer: what have you tried so far? Show us your code and we help you improve it!

Comment: @Zim84 i've thought about how you would implement this in JS but it doesn't seem possible. It seems that you'd need dev tools so can preprocess the CSS. Agree?

Comment: @timpeterson I think it would be a much better question if you show at least a tiny snippet of code. We really can't tell what you've done to start.

Comment: i think its very doable but it seems like whatever you are trying to do this is a terrible way to do it.

basically i'd document. querySelectorAll() and the loop through each and use window.getComputedStyle for the width and check with a subStr or regex if it ends in px,pt,etc. 

I suppose it could be a nice tool to find non flex elements to refactor.

Comment: @JonathanLam I don't know C++ or whatever the dev tools are written in. As I said, I can't imagine how one would do this in JS. I'm a pretty solid JS developer, check my SO rep., so think its unfair to assume I didn't think this through before asking.

Comment: @timpeterson, Looks like a lot of people downvote here when there's no thought process shown (in code).  I agree, it's a good question that hasn't been answered before.  I wonder if there's a way to sort of flatten the CSS so you can get the percent rather than pixel size.

Comment: Also, what will you be using it for?  that might help a bit to understand the final outcome.  For example, if you know the site you're using it on and you know the percentage values that have been used, you should be able to do some math and eliminate those normal percentage numbers.  You can possibly do all of the maths and take out any fractions longer than 2 or 3 digits?

Comment: @ntgCleaner added the use case above.

Comment: @timpeterson Good question? Opinion. Regardless.... Without knowing what exactly you're trying to do, I can't give you a non-terrible answer. You wouldn't need anything "dev tools"y though, as querySelectorAll() can be fed almost verbatim any CSS selector. Fetching linked stylesheet contents within JS should be possible, and because CSS is so simple, you just need to find any "fixed" width decls, grab their selector, and grow your eventual QSA call. It might be the naivest of approaches, but then, what you're trying to do is likely a naive approach, so *shrug*.

Comment: @timpeterson Do you know that the problem element is inside the iFrame? or outside of it?

Comment: @ntgCleaner people at Tawk.to claim it is on my page. Because they run a business to manage these widgets I give them the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: Can you possibly do a quick run down of Dom elements, going through each one, finding their widths and comparing it to the width of the iframe and or screen?

Comment: @timpeterson Better, but still lacks direction. You're saying why, but not what. Offsets how? Are you trying to just center the contents of the page? All I see is a mobile layout with no context of what you WANT it to look like.

Comment: @timpeterson Actually, added to that... If you mean the offset on the right, it's so that gigantic speech balloon/button doesn't overlap any of the content regardless of the content. Of course, if you had **outlined the iframe** so I could tell if I'm even correct in my guess as to what the iframe contains, that might help me divine what you're trying to do...